# Boto script to download latest file from s3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto

I like to write a boto python script to download the recent most file from the s3 bucket i.e. for eg I have 100 files in a s3 bucket I need to download the recent most uploaded file in it.

Is there a way to download the recent most modified file from S3 using python boto.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could list all of the files in the bucket and find the one with the most recent one (using the last_modified attribute).

```
>>> import boto
>>> c = boto.connect_s3()
>>> bucket = c.lookup('mybucketname')
>>> l = [(k.last_modified, k) for k in bucket]
>>> key_to_download = sorted(l, cmp=lambda x,y: cmp(x[0], y[0]))[-1][1]
>>> key_to_download.get_contents_to_filename('myfile')
```

Note, however, that this would be quite inefficient in you had lots of files in the bucket. In that case, you might want to consider using a database to keep track of the files and dates to make querying more efficient.

Answer (score 9):

To add to @garnaat's answer, you may be able to address the inefficiency by using `prefix` to reduce the matched files. Instead of `c.lookup`, this example would only search files in the `subdir` subbucket that start with `file_2014_`:

```
>>> import boto
>>> c = boto.connect_s3()
>>> bucket = c.get_bucket('mybucketname')
>>> bucket_files = bucket.list('subdir/file_2014_')
>>> l = [(k.last_modified, k) for k in bucket_files]
>>> key_to_download = sorted(l, cmp=lambda x,y: cmp(x[0], y[0]))[-1][1]
>>> key_to_download.get_contents_to_filename('target_filename')
```

Answer (score 3):

S3 launched versioning functionality of files in bucket http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Versioning.html.

You could get latest n files by calling s3client.listVersions(request) and specifying n if you want.See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/list-obj-version-enabled-bucket.html

Example is in java. Not sure if boto added API for versioning.